# Flexible array member of unnamed struct

Tags: c, language-lawyer, flexible-array-member

Consider the following example:

```
typedef struct test_flex_arr{
    size_t sz;
    struct {
        int i;
        const char *path;
    } info[];
} tfa;

int main(void){
    size_t sz = 100;
    tfa *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + sizeof (*((tfa*) NULL)).info[sz]);
    ptr->info[99].i = 10;
    printf("%d\n", ptr->info[99].i); //prints 10
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/PtHw3e)

I expected this program to crash but it runs just fine. As specified `6.5.3.4(p2)`:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. **If
>   the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
>   is evaluated**; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
>   is an integer constant

The type of the operand of `sizeof ((*((tfa*) NULL)).info)[sz]` is variable length array so the operand should be evaluated. But evaluation of the operand means derefencing `NULL` which I expected to lead to crash.

Is the behavior of the code well defined?

Comment: Too many parentheses here, but it looks like the sizeof-ed expression is not a flex array but one of it's elements.

Comment: The quote mentions VLAs not flexible arrays.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp FWIW a flex array member is an incomplete type, so `sizeof` should fail too. It's just that the expression here is neither VLA nor FAM

Comment: You should be using `sz * sizeof(ptr->info)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The `sz` is not a constant so it should be treated as a variable length array type. _If the size is an integer constant expression and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type; **otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type**_

Comment: The problem is that `*((tfa*) NULL)).info` is not a type, so adding `[sz]` doesn't create a variable length array type.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. But why does it even compile?

Comment: Yeah, looks like like it is. `....info[sz]` is an element of the array but not the array itself.

Comment: From inside out :) `((tfa*) NULL)` is of type `tfa*`. `(*((tfa*) NULL))` is of type `tfa`. This whole thing `.info` is your array. And adding `[sz]` is indexing it.

Comment: A flexible array member is not a variable length array. They are different things. A flexible array member has no defined size. A variable length array has a size defined during execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(*((tfa*) NULL)).info[sz]` is not a variable length array type, because `(*((tfa*) NULL)).info` is not a type.

So it's treating that as an ordinary expression, referring to the `sz` element of the array `(*((tfa*) NULL)).info`. Per the quoted specification, this is not evaluated, so the fact that it dereferences `NULL` doesn't cause undefined behavior. It simply returns the size of the array element, which is not dependent on the location of the array or the index. That's why it compiles without warning and doesn't crash.

But this doesn't produce the desired result. You're only getting the size of one element of the array, not the `sz` elements that you actually need to allocate space for. You need to multiply the size of an element by the number of elements. So use

```
tfa *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + sz * sizeof ptr->info[0]);
```

Comment: `sizeof ptr->info` this should probably be `sizeof ptr->info[0]`

Comment: Even if the `sizeof` operand were a type, a flexible array member is not a variable length array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But if the flexible array member were something like `int info[]`, you could write `sizeof(int[sz])`. That's the kind of notation that the spec is talking about.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Flexible array member has incomplete type, the type of variable length array is complete.

Comment: @SomeName: What are you trying to say?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant that trying to apply a`sizeof` to a flexible array member would cause constraint violation.